# Condicional SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla en la que aparecen en una columna 1 y 0, m gustaría realizar una consulta en la que si es 1 quiero que aparezca masculino y si es 0 femenino.

**el resultado seria una columna llamada genero en la que en vez de 1 y 0 se leería femenino o masculino.**

Pregunto también porque no se si esto realmente se puede hacer, gracias de antemano.

Edit he intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  id_customer as id_Cliente, firstname as Nombre, lastname as Apellidos ,id_gender as Genero, company as Empresa
    CASE
        WHEN id_gender = 1 THEN "Masculino"
        WHEN id_gender = 2 THEN "Femenino"
        ELSE "No ha elegido genero"
    END
    FROM ps_customer
```

Pero creo que no es correcto ya que no me aparece resultado ninguno.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario utilizar un condicional simplemente puedes utilizar una constante. Algo como: `SELECT 'Masculino' as genero FROM customer WHERE id_gender = 1`

Comment: umm es algo mas complicada la consulta, ya que genero es solo uno de los campos también tengo campos como nombre, apellidos, fecha de registro, etc.

Comment: Aún así puedes utilizar de la misma forma: `SELECT nombre, apellidos, fecha de registro, 'Masculino' as genero FROM customer WHERE id_gender = 1`, en caso de requerir ambos generos utilizar `union`, algo así: `(SELECT nombre, apellidos, fecha de registro, 'Masculino' as genero FROM customer WHERE id_gender = 1) UNION (SELECT nombre, apellidos, fecha de registro, 'Femenino' as genero FROM customer WHERE id_gender = 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto debes usar **CASE** en este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) puedes encontar más información.

```sql
SELECT
CASE
WHEN condicion1 THEN x
WHEN condicion2 THEN y
[ELSE z]
END
```

Comment: SELECT  id_customer as id_Cliente, firstname as Nombre, lastname as Apellidos ,id_gender as Genero, company as Empresa
CASE
    WHEN id_gender = 1 THEN "Masculino"
    WHEN id_gender = 2 THEN "Femenino"
    ELSE "No ha elegido genero"
END
FROM ps_customer     he realizado esta consulta pero no me la detecta como correcta.

Comment: SELECT
 id_customer as id_Cliente,
 firstname as Nombre,
 lastname as Apellidos,
 company as Empresa,
 CASE
  WHEN id_gender = 1 THEN "Masculino"
  WHEN id_gender = 2 THEN "Femenino"
 END AS Genero
FROM
 ps_customer

Comment: Infinitas gracias eso era!!!